# Taskbar Icons Disappear Until Hover

Tags: windows, taskbar

When I click the show system tray button, internet or volume button on the taskbar, all icons in the taskbar except the Start, Cortana and cascade view buttons disappear. They only reappear when I hover over where the icons should be. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I'm thinking it has to do with explorer.exe refreshing, but have no idea where to go from here.

I have tried sfc /scannow and DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth. The problem does not occur in safe mode or in other users, so I think it must be something with my current user.

[taskbar with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11tr1.png)

Comment: Set up a new, test Windows User Local Profile (Account). Log into the new Windows Account and test your taskbar icons. This appears it could be a profile issue.

Comment: Apologies - I re-read.  This sounded like a profile issue, and upon re-reading, it is definitely a profile issue. Copy your profile documents, email and such to a neutral (non-user) location, make a new user account, restore your data and when satisfied, delete the problem user account.